# Table reference not working properly when using \setcounter{table}{0} in appendix in latex

Tags: tables, hyperref, numbering, counters, appendix

I am trying to fix an issue with my latex document, and need help.

I am using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` environment in Latex. The issue is the following:

I have added an appendix using

```
\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}
```

and used

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

to generate table names as Table A1 and so on.

However, when I use `\setcounter` to restart the table numbering, my labels stop working. But if I remove the `\setcounter` command, my labels work perfectly, but then the table number continue from where I left before appendix, that is Table A6 and not Table A1.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

Table \ref{tab_main} is the first table.

\begin{table}
\centering
 \input{Main_Table}
\caption{Main Table}
\label{tab_main}
\end{table}

See table \ref{tab_appendix} in the appendix.

\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}

%\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\begin{table}
    \input{Appendix_Table}
    \caption{Appendix Table}
\label{tab_appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And here are tables that I have used:
Main_Table.tex

```
\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[H]
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\small
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\tiny
\end{tabularx}
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\smallskip
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Main}}}
\end{table}
\end{centre}
```

Appendix_Table.tex

```
\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[H]
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\small
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\tiny
\end{tabularx}
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\smallskip
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Appendix}}}
\end{table}
\end{centre}
```

Any help on this front would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: There are a number of things which should be changed but are probably not related to your problem.  Also, can you create a more minimal MWE?  Something without `\input`?

Comment: Rule number 1 of table creation under LaTeX: *Never* enclose a `table` environment in a `center` environment. Never, ever. No way, no how.

Comment: Please prepare a complete end compilable MWE that allows othes to reproduce the otuput you get. Code like `\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\smallskip
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Appendix}}}` should not be used outside of a `tabular` or similar environment, so I would expect quite a bunch  of error messages from the code fragments you provided so far.

Comment: Off-topic: you need to clean-up your preamble: each package let be loaded onse (remove all duplicate), package `hyperref` should be loaded last (with rare exception as is for example `cleveref`) in preamble.

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure that I do not duplicate or add them in wrong order. Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `\setcounter{table}{0}` does *not* cause a compilation problem.

Instead, the main problem would appear to be that your code tries to nest a `table` environment within another `table` environment. That simply cannot go well. For instance, in the main tex file, one finds the following code chunk:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
 \input{Main_Table}
\caption{Main Table}
\label{tab_main}
\end{table}
```

But in `Main_Table.tex`, one finds

```
\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[H]
...
\end{table}
\end{centre}
```

By the way, the name of the environment is `center`, not `centre`.

Incidentally, it's an absolute mistake to enclose a `table` environment inside a `center` environment. And, do please learn to use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline \hline \\[-1.8ex]`. Finally, the `subfigure` package has been deprecated for about 2 decades. Don't use it. Instead, use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

I would like to suggest that you clean up and simplify your code along the lines of the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,
graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,
footmisc,caption,pdflscape,%subfigure, %% 'subfigure' is deprecated
array,hyperref,
booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable,adjustbox,apacite, 
dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{MainTable.tex}
\begingroup\small
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} LCCCC @{}}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Heading} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Koo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Koo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Main}
\endgroup
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{AppendixTable.tex}
\begingroup\small
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} LCCCC @{}}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Heading} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Foo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Foo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Appendix}
\endgroup
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

Table \ref{tab_main} is the first table.

\begin{table}[h!]
  \input MainTable
  \caption{Main Table}
  \label{tab_main}
\end{table}

\noindent
See table \ref{tab_appendix} in the appendix.


\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0} % <-- this doesn't cause an error
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}

\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \input AppendixTable
  \caption{Appendix Table}
  \label{tab_appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment. Thanks for clarifying what you meant by "my labels stop working". I think you have two options for fixing the hyperlink aspect of the cross-referencing exercise.

- If you're ok with your tables being numbered as `A.1`, `A.2`, etc., all you need to do is add the instruction

  ```
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
  ```

  immediately after `\appendix` -- and, of course, drop the instructions `\setcounter{table}{0}` and `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}`.
- If the tables in Appendix A *must* be numbered as `A1`, `A2` etc, I suggest you employ the instructions

  ```
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand{\theHtable}{\thesection\arabic{table}} % for 'hyperref'
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  ```

  immediately after `\appendix`.

Should the document have an appendix `B` as well and if that appendix also contains `table` environments, you'll also need to run `\setcounter{table}{0}` after the second `\section` command in the appendix.

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the table and center environments from the Main_Table.tex file. However, references are working without set counter and not with set counter. So, the issue still remains. I am happy to get on a private chat and discuss

Comment: @AnishaGarg - Please see the addendum I posted to my answer.

Comment: Thank You! This works! :)

Comment: Also, when I add another appendix using ```\section{Appendix B}\label{appendix_b}```, my Appendix B starts somewhere in-between Appendix A and both are mixed up. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: @AnishaGarg - Please clarify what you mean by "my Appendix B starts somewhere in-between Appendix A and both are mixed up".

Comment: It means that ideally, Appendix B should come after all my tables in Appendix A end. That is when a new section should start. However, here, Appendix B starts from between the tables in Appendix A

Comment: @AnishaGarg - Not knowing the particulars of the contents of Appendices A and B, all I can suggest is that you load the `placeins` package and issue the instruction `\FloatBarrier` immediately before `\section{Appendix B}`.

Comment: This kind of worked. But the heading - Appendix B and some text still gets in Appendix A

Comment: @AnishaGarg - Please post a *new query* about this new problem. That way, far more people will get to see it  and, hopfully, provide uasable answers.

Comment: Sure, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a MWE.  Unfortunately, it doesn't reproduce your problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{mssymb, dirtytalk}% not found
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,
color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,
hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Test 1}
\label{tab_main}
\end{table}

See table \ref{tab_appendix} in the appendix.

\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\section{Second}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Test 2}
\label{tab_appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```